# certificate for push notification of passbook

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate, passbook

What is procedure and how to create certificate for push notification of passbook?

Using sandbox and they work for push notification( php-apns), but not work for passbook(using push token).

so please help for correct way to send push notification of passbook and how to create certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a Pass Type ID and a certificate in the Apple Developer portal (requires a paid membership).  You then connect to APNS using this certificate.

You also need to use the production APNS endpoint and port - there is no sandbox for passes.

Comment: when i use pass type id  .pem file in push notification it give error

Comment: Unable to set private key file `/var/www/html/passbookYII/vendor/files/passes/push.pem' in /home/devesh/Desktop/SimplePush1/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 23

Comment: failed to create an SSL handle in /home/devesh/Desktop/SimplePush1/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 23

Comment: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/devesh/Desktop/SimplePush1/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 23

Comment: You have a key error. Does your key match your certificate?

Comment: key means private key of keychain or password of pem file

Comment: Means you have a lot to learn....... Check the private key file matches the certificate file (google how to do a modulus check), check that the password (if any is correct for the key)z

Comment: not export private key(.p12) in keychain for pass type id.

Comment: what is url of passbook updation